# A markdown question: are custom list number formats possible?

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown

For list numbering, `1.`, `2.`, ... are used. Could I change this somehow, to use, say, (1), (2), ... or i), ii), ...?

Comment: There are some feature requests about this: [Add parenthesis to period as an accepted list delimiter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39684), [Ordered lists with letters as markers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156192), [Lists - additional alphanumeric item labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110731), etc. (Maybe you can find a few more.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you! As always, you provide very relevant information. Well then I guess instead of marking this as a duplicate I will also add the [tag:feature-request] tag ;)